Text resizing in iOS and Android apps
Doing a bit of benchmarking, looking for applications that are well responsive when Text resizing (accessibility).
Does anyone know any good examples of applications that look good when text resizing?

Asking for examples is very subjective. It's better to ask for guidelines with supporting examples. Please be specific about what you're looking for, what the context is to take into account etc.

@jazZRo
I apologize for the incorrect wording. It is recommendations with examples that I am looking for. I'm currently researching a good accessibility formula for our fintech app to make it easily accessible for visually impaired people - namely text resizing.
